# How to fetch customers review title from review.php to plugin file?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have added review title into my single product review section added a function into the review.php file and its working fine.

Now on my home page recent reviews coming through [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twb-woocommerce-reviews/)

Now I want to show the title here too I have tried this code to fetch the title from the review.php file

```
<?php echo get_review_title( $comment->comment_ID ); ?>
```

but its not working any idea how i can call the review title as same its working on single product area?

**please check both screenshot :**

**With title:** 
[image]

**On the home page without title through plugin:**
[image]
Much thanks for your suggestion in advance

Thanks

Comment: maybe ```echo get_the_title($post->ID);``` ?

Comment: this is for get the page title

Comment: this ```get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, "title", true );```  maybe ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633080/how-to-add-a-review-title-field-on-woocommerce-reviews-form